# Find rows where multiple columns have the same value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

```
library(tidyverse)
d = data.frame(x=c('A','B','C'), y=c('A','B','D'), z=c('X','B','C'), a=1:3)
print(d)
  x y z a
1 A A X 1
2 B B B 2
3 C D C 3
d %>% filter(x==y) # Returns rows 1 and 2
d %>% filter(x==z) # Returns rows 2 and 3
d %>% filter(x==y & x==z) # Returns row 2
```

How can I do what the very last line is doing with more concise syntax for some arbitrary set of columns? For example, `filter(all.equal(x,y,z))` which doesn't work but expresses the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With comparisons, on multiple columns, an easier option is to take one column out (`x`), while keeping the rest by looping in `if_all`, then do the `==`, so that it will return only TRUE when all the comparisons for that particular row is TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  filter(if_all(y:z, ~ x == .x))
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand what the `~` and the `.` are doing?

Comment: @BenS. it is a lambda expression for tidyverse.  You can change it to `function(u) x == u`  The `.x/.` is the default argument.  It depends on the function as well, i.e. for `imap` or `map2`, there can be two arguments i.e. `.x` and `.y`  For `pmap`, you can have `n` number of arguments, so, it would be `..1, ..2, ..3, ..4` etc

Comment: Thanks again. Supposing that I wanted to select my columns with `starts_with()` or `ends_with()`, will this approach still work? Or no, because I need to be able to take one out?

Comment: @BenS. You can use that i.e. `d %>% filter(if_all(c(where(is.character), -x), ~ x == .x))` or `d %>% filter(if_all(c(matches('y|z'), -x), ~ x == .x))`

Comment: OK so just for future reference, supposing I had named my columns `w,y,z` I would do `filter(if_all(y:z, ~ w == .x))`. Just want to make clear which `x` is which.

Comment: @BenS. You are right.  It can be any column you leave out ,i.e. `if_all(w:y, ~ z == .x)` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Same idea, with `across` instead of `if_all`;

```
d %>% 
  filter(across(y:z,  ~`==`(.x, x)))
```